# Create multiplatform Nuget from same project files

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, nuget

I want to create a Nuget package with multiple assemblies that are both .NET 4.5 and .NET Standard. Some consumers of the package are still on VS2012, so I can't just make a .NET Standard package.

The assemblies are still in active development, also by the VS2012 users.

The [docs for this situation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/porting/project-structure) suggest keeping the current CSPROJ files and creating new .NET Standard ones.
But I believe that keeping the project settings up-to-date on in both versions of the CSPROJ files will a problematic hassle. E.g. if when adding cross-project reference, a post-build task is changed, etc.

I see that projects such as [Json.NET](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/tree/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json) use one CSPROJ file for each platform, but I really think that this should be solved in a better way.

I would prefer it if I were able to create a script which could use `msbuild` to first build the projects for .NET 4.5 and then for .NET Standard, but it seems that the script would have to fix up the CSPROJ files' XML to change the target framework when building. If possible, I would like to avoid that also.

What other alternatives which makes keeping a single set of CSPROJ files possible are there?

Answer (score 0):

In the PackageReference world (i.e. if you are creating NETStandard libraries), you could simply put the following in the csproj file:

netstandard1.4**;net45**
  ...

Does this help you?

Comment: I know that the new "SDK style" CSPROJ files can have a <TargetFrameworks> element where I can specify mulitple target frameworks. But those CSPROJ files can only be read by VS2017, so it doesn't help me out until we get all people and projects moved from VS2012.